# Splitting up a run containing a joker

Tags: rummikub

If I have a run of 7, 8, 9, 10, J, 11, can I move the 7, 8 and 9 to begin another run, leaving the 10, joker, and 11 in a run of 3 or more?

Comment: You can't have a run that goes "10, J, 11" and you can't move the 8 and 9 without leaving the 7 orphaned.  It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @BJMyers perhaps that clarification you did is worthy of an answer, as based on what you say the answer would be "no you can't because..."

Answer (score 1):

Rummikub allows you to break up sets and runs to form new groupings as you wish, as long as all groupings on the board are valid at the end of the turn.  This means all sets and runs must consist of at least 3 tiles and follow the other rules for creating them.  Therefore you can always split a run into two (or more) smaller runs, provided that each of the smaller runs still has at least 3 tiles.

However, it's difficult to answer your question as written because the initial state of the tiles on the board is invalid.  A joker tile must "stand in" for another tile that would be valid in the run, so you can't have "10, J, 11" - there can't be a tile in between the 10 and 11.

If we assume that your initial state is a run of 7, 8, 9, 10, J, 12, then it is legal to pull the 7, 8, and 9 away to form a new run, leaving the 10, J, 12 as a valid run.

Comment: -1. I have played two editions of rummikub. In one rulebook there was a specific rule that "you may not split up a run containing a joker", in the other this rule didn't exist. Therefore the answer is *It depends on the edition you're playing. Check your rulebook.*

Comment: @AndyT That would be a great answer, provided that you can link to a version of the rulebook that contains that specific rule.

Comment: If the question wasn't closed, I would have tried exactly that. But I'm afraid that being limited to comments, I couldn't be bothered to do the research.